# How do I get a string multiple values using the same key name that aren't in an array found in a mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

mongodb is set up as so

```
_id:63457fde325244fe6b157dda
name:"Lisa"
number"248XXXXXXX"
sign:"scorpio"
createdAt:2022-10-11T14:38:22.991+00:00
updatedAt:2022-10-11T14:38:22.991+00:00
__v:0


_id:6345f0996e609ff4da70a6a9
name:"Alyssa"
number"248XXXXXXX"
sign:"vigo"
createdAt:2022-10-11T14:38:22.991+00:00
updatedAt:2022-10-11T14:38:22.991+00:00
__v:0
```

So I'm trying to pull all the values with the same key "sign" using mongodb.Basically all I've gotten so for is this..

```
function findSign() {
    sun = ["aries", "taurus", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "scorpio", "sagittarius", "capricorn", "aquarius", "pisces"]
    output= []
   for(i=0; i<sun.length;i++){
   User.find(
       {sign:sun[i]},
       
       (err, sign) => {
       sign[i].push(output),
       console.log(sign)
     })
   }   
}
```

I want just an output to be a string of

```
virgo
scorpio
```

Comment: Look into `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for filtering, [`distinct`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-distinct) to return only a single sign per type, and [`select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) to return only the `sign` field:

```
function findSign() {
  sun = [
    'aries',
    'taurus',
    'gemini',
    'cancer',
    'leo',
    'virgo',
    'libra',
    'scorpio',
    'sagittarius',
    'capricorn',
    'aquarius',
    'pisces',
  ];
  User.find({ sign: { $in: sun } })
    .distinct('sign')
    .select('sign -_id')
    .exec((err, res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```